# Mongo docker - Dockerfile with indexCreate

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile, database-indexes

I've got following problem:
Need to create mongodb docker image with some initial data and config, so I started writing Dockerfile:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:latest
EXPOSE 27017
ADD ./scripts /scripts
RUN mongo PBM /scripts/indexes
```

/scripts/indexes:

```
db.events.createIndex( {'x1':1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 0})
```

And here I've occured  first error, that I cannot connect to db:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
```

Any ideas ?

**SOLUTION**

need to use ENTRYPOINT against RUN, because when using the second one, db does not exist.

Comment: There is a way of making this work, that is have a docker image with some preinserted data, although it is not the prettiest. I wrote an answer (for elasticsearch) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526532/how-to-add-an-elasticsearch-index-during-docker-build/39873112#39873112

This will work best if you need a database with fixed data, because if you try to use a volume after this procedure it will break.

Answer (score -1):

Reason might be that you only exposeing port inside dockerfile, you need use `-p 27017:27017` while running image but don't remove `EXPOSE port` inside `Dockerfile`,

- `EXPOSE` is used to expose port and can access in others containers
- `EXPOSE` and `-p` used to access port in both host m other containers

Comment: where did you mentioned that its building error?  you clearly mentioned its "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused" at the end. So i have answered for first error which you got